# Finding death record of John Annear (b.1750, Probus; m.1775, Gwennap) in Cornwall?

Tags: 18th-century, vital-records, cornwall

I'm looking for any details about the death of John Annear, my 6th great grandfather.

John Annear was born 17 April, 1750 in Probus, Cornwall, England
Married Mary May (Born: 1749) 26 June, 1775 in Gwennap, Cornwall, England

Father - Samuel Annear (Born: 1722)
Mother - Elizabeth Barbery (Born: 1733)

Children
Christian Annear (Born: 1776)
Samuel Annear (Born: 1781)

Answer (score 2):

There was a John Annear buried at Gwennap on 27 Oct 1796.

I found this using the free Cornwall Online Parish Clerk (OPC) website which is a fantastic resource for those of us with Cornish ancestors.

The same site lists [baptisms for 10 children between the years of 1776 and 1792](http://www.cornwall-opc-database.org/search-database/baptisms/index.php?year_from=1775&year_to=1796&parish=Gwennap&forename1=forename&surname1=annear&forename2=john&forename3=forename&t=baptisms&bf=Search) to John and Mary Annear so this would fit with your John Annear.

However, there are [six other John Annears buried at Gwennap](http://www.cornwall-opc-database.org/search-database/burials/index.php?year_from=1790&year_to=1850&parish=Gwennap&forename1=John&surname1=Annear&t=burials&bf=Search) in the years leading up to what would have been his 100th birthday so you will be wise to investigate each to become confident about which is the correct one.

The last five of the above seem to involve a John Annear who would be too young to be yours.  However, the 1810 burial looks similarly feasible so you may need to look for Wills, Newspaper reports, etc to try and decide which is more likely to be his.